# Python Abstract Method Default Logic, super() method

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, super

I am coming from the Java world and I am having a hard time understanding the super() method as it relates to abstract methods.

I have an abstract class with an abstract method. This class' subclasses are responsible for querying my MySQL database and returning formatted reports to me. In half of the subclasses, they use the exact same logic to run the report. In the other half, each needs its own logic. Therefore I want to make `run_report` an abstract method.

```
class Report:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.user = 'root'
        self.passwd = ''
        self.host = '127.0.0.0.1'
        self.port = '80'
        self.db = 'animals'        
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.user, password=self.passd, db=self.db, host=self.host, port=self.port)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    @staticmethod
    def construct_query(query, external_data):
        finalQuery = query % external_data
        return finalQuery

    @abstractmethod
    def run_report(self, query):
        self.cursor.execute(self, query)
        results = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return data
```

Here is an example of an implementation of a class that uses the abstract method as is:

```
class SheepReport(Report):

    query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sheep WHERE alive = 1;"

    def run_report(query):
        super(Report, self).run_report(query)
```

This syntax seems arcane. My code is too incomplete to test run at the moment, and I'm trying to nip errors in the bud. Am I understanding abstract methods correctly?

By contrast, here is a class that overrides run_report:

```
 class CowReport(Report):

    query = "SELECT height, weight FROM cows WHERE name IN (%s);"

    def run_report(self):
        finalQuery = self.construct_query(query, "'Hilda', 'Gary'");
        self.cursor.execute(self, finalQuery)
        results = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return data
```

Am I on the right track? All the examples of super() and inheritance I've seen are going over my head, I think I need someone to dumb it down for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I sincerely hope this is just for learning purposes and not actual production code. Passing unsanitized user input into a query string equals to a full blown [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

With that out of the way...

Abstract classes are usually for defining interfaces, rather than concrete functionality. Nevertherless for what you're trying to do, an abstract class with only `query` defined as an abstract property, would simplify considerably your code.

```
class Report:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.user = 'root'
        self.passwd = ''
        self.host = '127.0.0.0.1'
        self.port = '80'
        self.db = 'animals'
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.user, password=self.passd, db=self.db, 
                                            host=self.host, port=self.port)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    @abstractproperty
    def query(self):
        return NotImplemented

    def construct_query(self, **external_data):
        finalQuery = self.query % external_data
        return finalQuery

    def run_report(self, **external_data):
        self.cursor.execute(self, self.construct_query(**external_data))
        results = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return results
```

With the above class, then you only need to have a subclass like the below:

```
class SheepReport(Report):

    @property
    def query(self):
        return "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sheep WHERE alive = 1;"
```

Don't mind the unconditional `self.query % external_data`. It will work with either template strings or plain strings with *empty* dictionary data.

Comment: You shouldn't mix external data and the query string.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I'll look up the difference between an abstract method and an abstract property!

Comment: OnlyDean I expanded a bit on the issue @Blender touched. Keep in mind that if this is actual code, it has serious security issues.

Comment: @ramtamplam -- This is not production code. It is a highly simplified version of the problem I'm facing. Even so, I think I've failed to express what I'm really asking (although the advice about Abstract Properties is enlightening. I have a LOT to learn about Python).

What I want to do is define a method, but allow some instantiations of the class to override it. I know this is possible in Java, but inheritance and polymorphism seem to work differently in Python in way I'm having trouble grasping.

Comment: @OnlyDean you don't need abstract classes/methods for that. Just define your method in a *normal* parent/base class and then override it in whatever subclass you deem necessary.

Comment: @rantanplan Oh! That is very simple. Like I said, I'm coming from Java where everything is overly complicated. In that case, when does one actually use an abstract method in Python?

Comment: @OnlyDean When you want non-concrete(with no implementation usually) classes, that mostly define an interface/protocol to which subclasses should adhere to. IDEs like PyCharm for example show warnings when one subclasses an ABC class without providing *concrete implementations* of the abstract methods/properties.